# How do I get CTR with events I created?

Tags: google-analytics

I created events for my site and they work great. I'd like to know their CTR though because those events are placed on links that show randomly throughout my website. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

If you want to track a single event, you can create a Objetice, but this count as a Goal, wich have a CTR (unique events/sessions , this a boolean var)

The second option is

Create a custom metrics,

[image]
and them use this metric in a custom report 
[image]

Keep in mind the Stack OverFlow Policy, you cannot ask not related code question